# document.createElement - conditionally add when value is not empty

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a callout using the Apple MapKit JS using `document.createElement` which is working. I would now like to only conditionally add elements such as website links when the url is not empty.

The data is coming from the following array:

```
    // Landmarks data
var sanFranciscoLandmarks = [
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7951315, -122.402986), title: "Transamerica Pyramid", phone: "+1-415-983-5420", url: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/", url2: "http://www.transamericapyramidcenter.com/"  },
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7954201, -122.39352), title: "Ferry Building", phone: "+1 (415) 983-8030", url: "http://www.ferrybuildingmarketplace.com", url2: "" },
    { coordinate: new mapkit.Coordinate(37.7785538, -122.514035), title: "Cliff House", phone: "+1 (415) 386-3330", url: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/", url2: "http://www.cliffhouse.com/" }
];
```

I'm creating the callout as follows:

```
// Landmark annotation callout delegate
var calloutDelegate = {
// Return a div element and populate it with information from the
// annotation, including a link to a review site.
calloutContentForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "review-callout-content";

    var link = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    link.href = annotation.landmark.url;
    link.textContent = "website";

    var addLine = element.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    var contact = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    contact.href = annotation.landmark.url2;
    contact.textContent = "contact";

    // Add more content.
    element.style.width = "240px";
    element.style.height = "100px";
    return element;
}
```

In the callout it is always showing both links:

[image]

I would like to only show the 2nd link if the value in `url2` from the array is not empty but being new to Javascript I can't work out if this is possible or what the correct syntax here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use an `if` statement to check if the value in url2 is not empty, like so:

```
    ...

    if (annotation.landmark.url2) {
        var contact = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
        contact.href = annotation.landmark.url2;
        contact.textContent = "contact";
    }

    ...
```

With this `if` statement, the code inside of it will only run if the content inside `annotation.landmark.url2` evaluates as true. It will evaluate as true if it is a string with some content in it, wich I imagine is what you are expecting to have, but it will evaluate as false if it's undefined, null, an empty string, or the number 0, to list some. This will correctly check if the value is not empty, so just this simple `if` statement should solve your problem