# Javascript - add string before link using document.createElement

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a callout using the Apple MapKit JS using document.createElement which is working by adding elements from an array that contains the data. I would now like to add a string in front of some of the elements - I have it been able to do this successfully for non links thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668200/document-createelement-conditionally-add-when-value-is-not-empty/75668358#75668358) but I can't work out how to do this for links.

Here's how the callout currently looks:

[image]

I would like to add some text before the website links (e.g. 'Main') that aren't part of the clickable link. Here's the code for the callout that gets created:

```
// Landmark annotation callout delegate
var calloutDelegate = {
// Return a div element and populate it with information from the
// annotation, including a link to a review site.
calloutContentForAnnotation: function(annotation) {
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "review-callout-content";

    var link = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    link.href = annotation.landmark.url;
    link.textContent = "website";
    
    var phone = element.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
    //phone.textContent = annotation.landmark.phone;
    phone.textContent = `Phone: ${annotation.landmark.phone}`;

    var contact = element.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
    contact.href = annotation.landmark.url2;
    contact.textContent = "contact";

    // Add more content.
    element.style.width = "240px";
    element.style.height = "100px";
    return element;
}
```

Comment: You can just append an `<a>` inside a `<p>`.

Comment: var text = element.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
    
    text.textContent = "main";

Comment: Add before the link element

Comment: And just to complement Stéphane's comment, in the link you do `text.appendChild`, not `element.appendChild`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me thanks to the comments above:

```
var text = element.appendChild(document.createElement("p")); 
text.textContent = "Main: ";
var website = text.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
website.href = annotation.landmark.url;
website.textContent = "website";
```